# My Minecraft Launcher won't work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

When I bring up the launcher, I see the updates and stuff like normal. I try to click on the button that says Play and all it does is say Preparing for a few seconds, then it goes back to saying Play. No matter how many times I press Play, nothing happens. I use a Mac, I have the most recent Launcher and the most recent Java. Here is a copy of the log I get when I press Play:

```
[12:17:24 INFO]: Minecraft Launcher 1.5.3 (through bootstrap 5) started on osx...
[12:17:24 INFO]: Current time is Dec 29, 2014 12:17:24 PM
[12:17:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Mac OS X'
[12:17:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.version') == '10.9.5'
[12:17:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'x86_64'
[12:17:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.6.0_65'
[12:17:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Apple Inc.'
[12:17:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'
[12:17:24 INFO]: Refreshing local version list...
[12:17:24 INFO]: Refreshing remote version list...
[12:17:25 INFO]: Refresh complete.
[12:17:25 INFO]: Loaded 2 profile(s); selected 'gans4728'
[12:17:25 INFO]: Refreshing auth...
[12:17:25 INFO]: Logging in with access token
[12:17:29 INFO]: Getting syncinfo for selected version
[12:17:29 INFO]: Queueing library & version downloads
[12:17:29 ERROR]: Couldn't save version info to install PartialVersion{id='1.8.1', updateTime=Mon Nov 24 09:13:31 EST 2014, releaseTime=Mon Nov 24 09:13:31 EST 2014, type=RELEASE}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Whit/Library/Application Support/minecraft/versions/1.8.1/1.8.1.json (Not a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:218) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.LocalVersionList.saveVersion(LocalVersionList.java:84) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.MinecraftVersionManager.installVersion(MinecraftVersionManager.java:333) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.launcher.game.runner.AbstractGameRunner.playGame(AbstractGameRunner.java:101) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.game.GameLaunchDispatcher$1.run(GameLaunchDispatcher.java:111) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [?:1.6.0_65]
[12:17:59 INFO]: Getting syncinfo for selected version
[12:17:59 INFO]: Queueing library & version downloads
[12:17:59 ERROR]: Couldn't sync local and remote versions
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Whit/Library/Application Support/minecraft/versions/1.8.1/1.8.1.json (Not a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:218) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.LocalVersionList.saveVersion(LocalVersionList.java:84) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.MinecraftVersionManager.syncVersion(MinecraftVersionManager.java:315) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.launcher.game.runner.AbstractGameRunner.playGame(AbstractGameRunner.java:76) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.game.GameLaunchDispatcher$1.run(GameLaunchDispatcher.java:111) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [?:1.6.0_65]
[12:17:59 ERROR]: Couldn't save version info to install CompleteVersion{id='1.8.1', updatedTime=Mon Nov 24 09:13:31 EST 2014, releasedTime=Mon Nov 24 09:13:31 EST 2014, type=RELEASE, libraries=[Library{name='com.ibm.icu:icu4j-core-mojang:51.2', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.6', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='com.paulscode:codecjorbis:20101023', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='com.paulscode:codecwav:20101023', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='com.paulscode:libraryjavasound:20101123', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='com.paulscode:librarylwjglopenal:20100824', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='com.paulscode:soundsystem:20120107', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='io.netty:netty-all:4.0.23.Final', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='com.google.guava:guava:17.0', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='commons-io:commons-io:2.4', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='net.java.jinput:jinput:2.0.5', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='net.java.jutils:jutils:1.0.0', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='com.mojang:authlib:1.5.17', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='com.mojang:realms:1.7.6', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.0-beta9', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.0-beta9', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.9.1', rules=[Rule{action=ALLOW, os=null}, Rule{action=DISALLOW, os=OSRestriction{name=OSX, version='null', arch='null'}}], natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl_util:2.9.1', rules=[Rule{action=ALLOW, os=null}, Rule{action=DISALLOW, os=OSRestriction{name=OSX, version='null', arch='null'}}], natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:2.9.1', rules=[Rule{action=ALLOW, os=null}, Rule{action=DISALLOW, os=OSRestriction{name=OSX, version='null', arch='null'}}], natives={LINUX=natives-linux, WINDOWS=natives-windows, OSX=natives-osx}, extract=com.mojang.launcher.versions.ExtractRules@62e8ef4c}, Library{name='org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.9.2-nightly-20140822', rules=[Rule{action=ALLOW, os=OSRestriction{name=OSX, version='null', arch='null'}}], natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl_util:2.9.2-nightly-20140822', rules=[Rule{action=ALLOW, os=OSRestriction{name=OSX, version='null', arch='null'}}], natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:2.9.2-nightly-20140822', rules=[Rule{action=ALLOW, os=OSRestriction{name=OSX, version='null', arch='null'}}], natives={LINUX=natives-linux, WINDOWS=natives-windows, OSX=natives-osx}, extract=com.mojang.launcher.versions.ExtractRules@2ab6994f}, Library{name='net.java.jinput:jinput-platform:2.0.5', rules=null, natives={LINUX=natives-linux, WINDOWS=natives-windows, OSX=natives-osx}, extract=com.mojang.launcher.versions.ExtractRules@3a0b2771}, Library{name='tv.twitch:twitch:6.5', rules=null, natives=null, extract=null}, Library{name='tv.twitch:twitch-platform:6.5', rules=[Rule{action=ALLOW, os=null}, Rule{action=DISALLOW, os=OSRestriction{name=LINUX, version='null', arch='null'}}], natives={LINUX=natives-linux, WINDOWS=natives-windows-${arch}, OSX=natives-osx}, extract=com.mojang.launcher.versions.ExtractRules@324a897c}, Library{name='tv.twitch:twitch-external-platform:4.5', rules=[Rule{action=ALLOW, os=OSRestriction{name=WINDOWS, version='null', arch='null'}}], natives={WINDOWS=natives-windows-${arch}}, extract=com.mojang.launcher.versions.ExtractRules@3b8845af}], mainClass='net.minecraft.client.main.Main', jar='null', minimumLauncherVersion=14}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Whit/Library/Application Support/minecraft/versions/1.8.1/1.8.1.json (Not a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:218) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.LocalVersionList.saveVersion(LocalVersionList.java:84) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.MinecraftVersionManager.installVersion(MinecraftVersionManager.java:333) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.launcher.game.runner.AbstractGameRunner.playGame(AbstractGameRunner.java:101) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.game.GameLaunchDispatcher$1.run(GameLaunchDispatcher.java:111) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [?:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [?:1.6.0_65]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any saves or servers you want to save, skip steps 3

1. Open Finder
2. press `command+shift+g` and enter `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/
3. Drag the `saves/` folder and `server.dat` to your desktop (or anywhere you can find them later)
4. press `command+shift+g` and enter `~/Library/Application Support/`
5. Delete the folder `minecraft/`
6. Launch the launcher and try again.

If this is successful, do steps 1 and 2, and move your `saves/` and `server.dat` back